# Adding multiple AND/OR statements with Magento

Tags: magento

Using Magento 1.9.x, I'm trying to create a ORM query with AND/OR statements, which should come out looking something like this:

```
    select a.*
    FROM main_table a
    where (a.updated is not null
            a.updated BETWEEN '2012-11-01' AND '2012-12-01')
        OR (a.updated is null
            AND p.created_at BETWEEN '2012-11-01' and '2012-12-01')
```

I've tried several different implementations similar to this and can't seem to find anything that gets me any more data than multiple collections of empty parenthesis.

```
    $collection = Mage::getModel('main_table')->getCollection();
    $collection->addFieldToFilter(array(
        array('a.updated', 'notnull' => true),
        array('a.created', 'notnull' => true)
    ));
    $collection->load(true,true);
```

Any ideas on how to make this work?

I've seen several people say to use addAttributeToFilter, however, that's only used when you're working on an EAV table, which this isn't, so I don't have that method available to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('main_table')->getCollection();
$collection
    ->getSelect()
    ->where('a.updated is not null AND a.updated BETWEEN '2012-11-01' AND '2012-12-01')
    ->orWhere('a.updated is null AND p.created_at BETWEEN '2012-11-01' and '2012-12-01');
echo collection->getSelect(); //Check if select is the same what you want
```

You may write better where condition with quoting, this is just an example. $collection->getSelect() is a Zend_Db_Select (http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/ru/zend.db.select.html)